# (edgeLoopFrom) doesn't work for a moving object inside a frame

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm looking for a way to move a ball inside a frame. I set up a square spriteNode and make its physicsBody property to be of edge type. I then put the ball inside it.

I can't get the contact between the two and the ball runs off the frame.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let square = SKSpriteNode ()
    var ball = SKShapeNode ()


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.backgroundColor = .white

    //building the frame
    square.size = CGSize (width: self.size.width * 0.8 , height: self.size.width * 0.8)
    square.position = CGPoint (x: self.size.width / 2 , y: self.size.height / 2 )
    square.color = .orange
    square.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(square)

    square.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFrom: square.frame)
    square.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    square.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    square.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    square.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    square.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    square.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    square.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2
    square.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2

    //making the moving ball

    ball = SKShapeNode (circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.strokeColor = .black
    ball.lineWidth = 2
    ball.fillColor = .blue
    ball.position = CGPoint (x: self.size.width / 2 , y: self.size.height/2 )

    ball.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(ball)

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1




}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    square.zRotation -= .pi/36
}
```

}

I even tried to add ball to the square but nothing happened.

Comment: I'm stunned too! Here's what I did: created a new spritekit game project, replaced the contents of the GameScene file with your contents and ran it on a real device (compiled on xcode 9beta, running on ipad air with ios 10.3). The ball goes through. BUT when I set the position of both the square and the ball to CGPoint.zero, the ball did indeed stay inside the square.

No idea why :(

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, your ball and your square are both bottom left corner, so your ball starts inside of a wall